# Select Latest records by comparing 2 identical tables

Tags: sql

I have 2 identical source tables with same columns but only values are different. Both tables do not have any primary keys.

I want to get the latest records out of those 2 tables based on these conditions:

1. should compare both Test1 and Test2 and based on latest scan date and BiosID it should return the value.
2. If BiosID is null, it should check for latest scan date and SerialNumber.
3. If both BiosID and SerialNumber are null, it should check for Hostname.

TEST1:

```
MachineID | Scandate   | Account | BiosID     | Serial number | Hostname |
1000      | 10-01-2016 | A       | Abcd1111   | null          |     null |
1001      | 11-01-2016 | B       | null       | 7890          |      XYZ |
1002      | 12-02-2016 | C       | null       | null          |      PQR |
1003      | 13-01-2016 | D       | null       | null          |      DEF |
```

Test2:

```
MachineID | Scandate   |    Account |   BiosID  |   Serial number | Hostname |
1000      | 10-02-2016 |          W |   Abcd1111|            1234 |      ABC |
1001      | 11-02-2016 |          X |   null    |            7890 |     null |
1002      | 12-01-2016 |          Y |   null    |            null |     null |
1003      | 13-02-2016 |          Z |   null    |             null|      DEF |
```

The result table should be 
Test3:

Result:

```
MachineID | Scandate   |    Account |   BiosID   |  Serial number | Hostname |
1000      | 10-02-2016 |          W |   Abcd1111 |           1234 |      ABC |
1001      | 11-02-2016 |          X |   Null     |           7890 |     null |
1002      | 12-02-2016 |          C |   null     |           null |      PQR |
1003      | 13-02-2016 |          Z |   null     |           null |      DEF |
```

Previously, I had written a code only to check latest scan and BiosID.

query:

```
WITH Combined As(
SELECT MachineID,LastHWScan,Account,BiosID,SerialNumber,HostName
FROM TEST1

UNION 
SELECT MachineID,LastHWScan,Account,BiosID,SerialNumber,HostName
FROM TEST2
)
, Ordered AS(
SELECT MachineID,LastHWScan,Account,BiosID,SerialNumber,HostName,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BiosID ORDER BY LastHWScan DESC) AS rn
FROM Combined
)

INSERT INTO TEST3(MachineID,LastHWScan,Account,BiosID,SerialNumber,HostName)
SELECT MachineID,LastHWScan,Account,BiosID,SerialNumber,HostName FROM Ordered
WHERE rn=1
```

But if BiosID is null, I cannot get the result which is required.
So can anyone please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could have changed the format of the assignment question !

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BiosID ORDER BY LastHWScan DESC) as rn
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY LastHWScan, SerialNumber DESC) as rn2
, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Hostname DESC) as rn3

INSERT INTO TEST3(MachineID,LastHWScan,Account,BiosID,SerialNumber,HostName)
    SELECT MachineID,LastHWScan,Account,BiosID,SerialNumber,HostName FROM Ordered
    WHERE (BiosID IS NOT NULL AND rn = 1)
    OR (BiosID IS NULL AND SerialNumber IS NOT NULL AND rn2 = 1)
    OR (BiosID IS NULL AND SerialNumber IS NULL AND rn3 = 1)
```

Comment: @HelpSeeker What was your solution you ended up using?